# Azure VM TCP idle timeout

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp, ftp, azure-virtual-machine

I have a problem with setting up a FTP Server on a Azure VM.
In normal using the server runs great. Problem are coming with large file transfer over passive FTP connection.

**Setup**

FTP-Server software is a FileZilla Server.
Azure VM endpoint, Windows Firewall and Filezilla are configurated to use port 10000-10009 for passive connections.
The client is a 3rd party device.

**Problem**

On large file transfers with a duration over 4min the connection gets an idle timeout.

I found a Microsoft blog entry where is written:

*"When FTP is transferring large files, the elapsed time for transfer may exceed 4 minutes, especially if the VM size is A0. Any time the file transfer exceeds 4 minutes, the Azure SLB will time out the idle TCP/21 connection, which causes issues with cleanly finishing up the FTP transfer once all the data has been transferred. [..] Basically, FTP uses TCP/21 to set everything up and begin the transfer of data. The transfer of data happens on another port. The TCP/21 connection goes idle for the duration of the transfer on the other port. When the transfer is complete, FTP tries to send data on the TCP/21 connection to finish up the transfer, but the SLB sends a TCP reset instead."*

Now... for my 3rd party client is it not possible to set it up to send a TCP keepalive command to avoid idle timeout.

**Question**

How can I tell the Azure VM to not close idel TCP connection after 4min?

I even don't understand why this is happens because this violates the TCP specifications ([RFC 5382](http://filezilla-project.org/specs/rfc5382.txt) makes this especially clear its 2h 4m in normal). In other words, Azure that is dropping idle connections too early cannot be used for long FTP transfers.

Please help!

Regards

Steffen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two solutions!

**1.**
It is possible to set the timeout of VM endpoints up to 30 minutes.

Powershell command to do this is:

`> Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyService" -Name "MyVM" | Set-AzureEndpoint -Name "MyEndpoint" -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 30 | Update-AzureVM`

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/azure/dn495219.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**2.** Create ILIP (instance level IP)

You can create a ILIP to bypass the VM webservice enpoint layer. The PowerShell command to do this is:

`Get-AzureVM -ServiceName “MyService” -Name “MyVM” | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName "MyNewEndpoint" | Update-AzureVM`

More information [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/).

Comment: is there a way to do this on classic vm using azure-cli ?

Comment: No only possible with PowerShell, but yes classic VM will support this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of Filezilla (3.14.1) and you can set Filezilla to send Keep-Alive packets, which would be recommended you try that first, rather than attempting to alter the default Azure load-balancer timeouts. However, the load balancer timeouts are user-configurable (ie: under your control) and details can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout/

To set keep-alive commands on in Filezilla:

•Open the FileZilla "Edit" menu and select "Settings." On a Mac, open the "FileZilla" menu and choose "Preferences."

•Select the "FTP" page in the "Connection" section of the Settings dialog box. Look for the "FTP Keep-Alive" section of the page.

•Activate the "Send FTP keep-alive commands" box in the "FTP Keep-alive" section. This sends commands between FileZilla and the FTP server at short intervals, resetting the time-out function and preventing the server from closing the connection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, as I wrote above "for my 3rd party client is it not possible to set it up to send a TCP keepalive command to avoid idle timeout", so sorry this is no option.